# TDataSource TDBMemo not in Insert or Browse mode

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, nexusdb

I have a DBLookupComboBox that lists values from 1 table that I'm selecting a value from.

When the value is selected, I want the 2 DBMemo Boxes I have to be able to input/edit into to insert/update into another table.

But They don't allow me to enter into them.  I assume because it's state is dsInactive.

How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the state is dsInactive, that means that the dataset isn't active, so it can't be edited.  In your setup code, try saying `MyDataset.Active := true;`.  This will fire its query and load the results into the dataset for you to view and edit.